# How to edit C# library files

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, websocket

I'm having a problem communicating my C# application to my web application with the socket library [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) I'm using.

I'm trying to send an array but the socket library can only sends/receives string as the message. I know I can send the array as a string and get it stringified on my C# app but I have some specific reason not to do that.

[image]

As per the image above you can see that the .cs file is locked and I'm not permitted to make any changes. I believe the developer had some firm reasons for setting the message variable to String **ONLY**.

Any idea?

Comment: You've linked to the source code of Fleck - can't you simply change the code to suit your needs and not worry about the library being locked?

Comment: For reasons why only strings, it looks like it is based on Nugget which was created **before** binary data was supported. See here: http://nugget.codeplex.com/discussions/267587

Comment: @JamesThorpe Good to know that. Is it possible to alter the assembly file? I do not know how to get the original source...

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize the array and use Send(byte[]) to transfer the object as bytes with a BinaryFormatter or you can use a XmlSerializer and use Send(string)

Answer (score 1):

The file is showing as "locked" because it's not a real file - it's been auto generated based on the contents of the assembly you've referenced, showing you how the original source *may* have looked. If you want to make any *actual* changes, you'll need to get the original source (which you linked to in your question), change it (licence permitting) and rebuild it.

Having said that, it appears to be a wrapper interface for web sockets, they only support binary or string data anyway, so at some level you're going to have to convert your message to one of those types. You may as well perform that conversion in your code before it makes it to the library.

Answer (score 1):

It's a library file, which means you can only access the code, *not edit it*.

What you **can** do is create extension properties or methods, meaning you can pass override methods the `Send` method and pass it an array.

You inherit the code from `IWebSocketConnection` using `:` as such:

`public interface IMyWebSocketExtended : IWebSocketConnection`

and then create override methods which accept the types that you need.

Alternatively you can extract the data from the array before passing it to `IWebSocketConnection` and save yourself the hassle :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve this is to extends the methods.

```
public interface CustomWebSocket : IWebSocketConnection
```

For instance, once you have extended the method, you may modify the content and use it.

You may want to look into the source code and checkout the content first.